# Why is the For function not working as expected?

Tags: c

I'm new to basic C++. And I'm trying the For function with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Tap n=");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++);
    {
        printf("\n%d", i);
    }
}
```

When I enter n=123, the result is 124. Doesn't run from 0 to 123. Why

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this site is English only.

Comment: 1. English please 2. please format the code right

Comment: I'm new to basic C++. And I'm trying the For function with this code: #include <stdio.h> int main() {int n; printf("Tap n="); scanf("%d", &n); int i; enter code here for (i = 0; i <= n; i++); {printf("\n%d", i);}} When I enter n=123, the result is 124. Doesn't run from 0 to 123. Why

Comment: Have you learned to use a debugger? This would be a very good time to learn, enter n as 5 and watch what happens, and how many times you go around the loop.

Comment: `for` is not a function. Text body says C++, tag says C, code could be either.  Pick one.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Your for-statement ends with a semi-colon, which means *"There is no code to loop!"*

```
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++);  // <== Remove the semi-colon.
```

2.) You run the loop while `i` is ***less-than-or-equal-to*** the final value of 124.
If you want it to go between 0 and 123, set your loop condition to be `i < n`

---

A typical for-loop looks like:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)   // Condition is < , not <=
{                         // No semi-colon after for-loop!
    /* BODY Statements */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- `for (i = 0; i <= n; i++);` // the semicolon prevents the loop from doing anything
- `for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)` // run n+1 times, wrong
- `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)` // run n times, correct

Change the loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    printf("\n%d", i);
}
```